# How to get String in response using Retrofit 2?

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I would like to understand how Retrofit works, but the official documentation is very weak.

I need to make a very simple `GET` request and get the response as a `String`.

Now I use standard `HTTPUrlConnection` and it works nicely, just request - response

Can anyone tell me how to get a `String` response without converting it to an object or something like that?

Comment: I've found their examples to be sufficient although the second version changes did take some research. You need to at post what you've got so far and then people will look and tell you where your problem is. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @Aleksey You can simply pass String in Call<String> getString();

Answer (score 15):

You can use ScalarsConverterFactory for strings and both primitives and their boxed types to text/plain bodies.
Add this dependency to your build.gradle file:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
```

Try this:

```
public interface ExampleService {
@GET("/users/{user}/repos")
Call<String> listRepos(@Path("user") String user);
}
```

And add ScalarsConverterFactory to your builder:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
.baseUrl(BASE_URL)
.addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
.build();
```

You can then retrieve this string like this:

```
Call<String> call = exampleService.listRepos(user);
Response<String> response = call.execute();  
String value = response.body();
```